# Alternative of WKInterfaceController openParentApplication in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to open the Swift iOS app from Watchkit action but I am unable to find openParentApplication method

```
 // Register notifications in iOS
  WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(userInfo) {
    (replyInfo, error) -> Void in
    // Callback here if needed                
  }
```

What is the alternative of openParentApplication in Swift now ?

Answer (score 0):

if it could still be useful, on watchOS 2 that method is not longer available as described on the documentation:

> This method is not available for WatchKit extensions running in
>   watchOS 2. Watch apps running in watchOS 2 must use the Watch
>   Connectivity framework to communicate with the companion iOS app. For
>   more information, see Watch Connectivity Framework Reference.